# Nginx Proxy_pass to cloudfront URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

We are trying to proxy_pass from nginx to AWS Cloudfront URL.

Something like below.
dare12381.cloudfront.net CNAME to example.com

And, In Nginx proxy config,

```
location / {
     proxy_pass example.com
}
```

Is it possible to have this setup?

Thanks and Regards!!!

Comment: What is the purpose of using CloudFront to do a CName mapping instead of doing it in DNS? Do you plan to route to different services (Not only limiting to example.com from the same external url?

Comment: @Ashan 
Yes. We are routing to different service (openshift route).

Comment: Can you also mention the use case you are going to achieve in using a NGINX proxy?